# why custom camera capturing a portion of the screen?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-image-capture

Hi I am using custom camera view in my application, It was working fine in some devices, but in 1+3t device it's capturing only a portion of the screen.
I've searched a lot but couldn't get the answer. Please help me to solve this.

code:

```
 @Override
    protected void prepareCameraOutputs() {
        try {
            if (configurationProvider.getMediaQuality() == Configuration.MEDIA_QUALITY_AUTO) {
                camcorderProfile = CameraHelper.getCamcorderProfile(currentCameraId, configurationProvider.getVideoFileSize(), configurationProvider.getMinimumVideoDuration());
            } else
                camcorderProfile = CameraHelper.getCamcorderProfile(configurationProvider.getMediaQuality(), currentCameraId);

            final List<Size> previewSizes = Size.fromList(camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes());
            final List<Size> pictureSizes = Size.fromList(camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes());
            List<Size> videoSizes;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10)
                videoSizes = Size.fromList(camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes());
            else videoSizes = previewSizes;

            videoSize = CameraHelper.getSizeWithClosestRatio(
                    (videoSizes == null || videoSizes.isEmpty()) ? previewSizes : videoSizes,
                    camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth, camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight);

            photoSize = CameraHelper.getPictureSize(
                    (pictureSizes == null || pictureSizes.isEmpty()) ? previewSizes : pictureSizes,
                    configurationProvider.getMediaQuality() == Configuration.MEDIA_QUALITY_AUTO
                            ? Configuration.MEDIA_QUALITY_HIGHEST : configurationProvider.getMediaQuality());

            if (configurationProvider.getMediaAction() == Configuration.MEDIA_ACTION_PHOTO
                    || configurationProvider.getMediaAction() == Configuration.MEDIA_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED) {
                previewSize = CameraHelper.getSizeWithClosestRatio(previewSizes, photoSize.getWidth(), photoSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                previewSize = CameraHelper.getSizeWithClosestRatio(previewSizes, videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while setup camera sizes.");
        }
    }
```

and calling this 
      camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                        prepareCameraOutputs();
                        if(futurFlashMode != null) {
                            setFlashMode(futurFlashMode);
                            futurFlashMode = null;
                        }
I am using https://github.com/florent37/CameraFragment/tree/master/camerafragment

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @Edric - please check now